# JenkinsFile block access to Shared Library Code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that uses a shared library that has a common functionality available. My problem is that I am able to import on my Jenkinsfile the code under the /src folder.

I would like to block that code to be accessed, meaning that I could only call the code inside the /vars folder.

Is such behavior possible?